# Как узнать название(тип) тега по его классу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть тэги:

```
<input type="text" name="profession" placeholder="Ответ" class="qn_1">
```

Как узнать средствами js, какой тэг у класса `qn_1` ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("output").text(Array.prototype.map.call($(".qn_1"), function (el) {
  return el.tagName.toLowerCase();
}).join("\n"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" name="profession" placeholder="Ответ" class="qn_1">
<div class="qn_1"></div>
<pre><output></output></pre>
```

Comment: что-то ты перемудрил :-) у jQuery есть свой `map`

Comment: @Grundy, но ведь у него нет `join`...

Comment: Ага, зато есть `toArray` который вернет массив у которого есть :-) ну и в крайнем случае `join` можно также через call применить

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.qn_1').tagName);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="profession" placeholder="Ответ" class="qn_1">
```